# Need help updating Angular/cli after receiving "incompatible peer dependency"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

I'm trying to update Angular, so I ran:

> />ng update

It said there were some packages to update.

@angular/cli, @angular/core, @angular/google-maps

[image]

so next I ran

> />ng update @angular/cli

and I get these messages:

> Package "ngx-spinner" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^10.0.0" (extended), would install "12.2.12").

> Package "ngx-spinner" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^10.0.0" (extended), would install "12.2.12").
>
> ✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
> Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
> You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
> See "/private/var/folders/lx/xgvtsnmd7f1325jk52qqqndc0000gn/T/ng-h3yLjW/angular-errors.log" for further details.

Next I updated the ngx-spinner package to the latest version.

> />npm update ngx-spinner

and now I have the latest version

> ngx-spinner@12.0.0

**Problem** - I run the ng update @angular/cli command again and I still receive the same error message.

**QUESTION** - should I use --force and force install @angular/cli, and then force install the other 2 npm packages @angular/core and @angular/google-maps? They had similar peer dependency error messages when I tried to update them too.

After removing node_modules and package-lock I tried running npm install again and received this message.

[image]

Comment: Try to update @angular/core and @angular/common before you update @angular/cli

Comment: If you look at my post, you'll see I already tried that. Look at the bottom of my post under QUESTION. I get the ngx-spinner dependency and @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: Or 1) remove ngx-spinner 2) update angular 3) reinstall ngx-spinner

Comment: Note you probably shouldn't go directly from 10 to 12 at all, the Angular guidance (see e.g. https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-12.0) is to do one major version at a time.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to update these packages? Uninstall dep. then reinstall them later?

Comment: Hi Jon. I think I kinda already missed the boat on that because I already did a ng update. What do you recommend? Do I go and update all using specific versions? I don't even remember what I was on. I think 9, but I could be wrong, maybe 10. I know Angular and Angular Cli 10 is installed and being used now. This is what is shows when I do ng version

Comment: Let me try the link recommendations.

Comment: I'm still getting dependency errors when going  from 10->12. Should I just use force?

Comment: Hi Drenai. I tried to remove 1-2 more packages including node_modules and package-lock and then ran npm install. I received an error. I'll post it above.

Comment: oh dear, jumping multiple angular versions = certain doom - if you are using git restore to the place you were at before you did the ng update and then update one version at a time and after each update test everything works before doing the next one

Comment: I figured it out about an hour ago or so. I had to do a bunch of stuff. But I finally got ng v12 installed and running. I think all is good now.